# Sidebar menu not extending to bottom of page (and CSS driving me crazy..)

Tags: html, css, menu, sidebar

I've been trying to create a simple website layout with a side bar that would stretch all the way down to the footer, a main content area, and a footer below all that (settling nicely at the bottom of the screen when there isn't much content on the page).

After hours of trial and error and research of codes I thought I had finally reached my goal... Until I tried adding loads of content in the "content" area, and realized that the sidebar won't stretch as long as the content then...

I tried adding the "height: 100%" to the menu element but that obviously won't do the trick

```
#sidebar {
width: 3em;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 2.5em;
background: #111111;
color: #FFFFFF; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dn8srqaq/1/

Any idea how to fix that ?

Thanks very much..

Comment: Thanks v much Manish and Alaam, it did the trick! Turns out I had actually deleted by mistake a semi-colon on the "position: relative;" attribute of the #wrapper div, hence breaking the design... my bad and thanks again!

Comment: you could upvote my answer, and you're most welcome :)

Comment: I did but don't think it shows as my rep is still below 15.. thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Just add `position:relative` of the parent class and then add `height: 100%` to `#sidebar`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -2.5em; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
  position: relative
  z-index: 0;
}

#footer {
  height: 2.5em;
}
#footer-content {
  border-top: 3px solid #000000;
  height: 2.3em;
  padding-top: 0em;
  padding-left: 4em;
}

#footer-content a {
  font: 0.8em Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-left: 5%;
  color: #444444;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 2.5em;
}

#footer-content a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #footer-content {
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
  }
  #footer-content a {
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    display: block;
  }
}
.push {
  height: 2.5em;
  clear: both;
}

#content {
  height: 100%;
  position:relative;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 2.5em;
  background: #111111;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 100%;
}
#main {
  margin-left: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
      <div id="sidebar">Sidebar<br/>Sidebar<br/>Sidebar<br/></div>
      <div id="main" style="background: #ffcccc;">
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
          Main<br />
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="push"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <div id="footer-content">
    <a href="about/">About</a>
    <a href="legal/">Legal stuff</a>
    <a href="help/">Help</a>
    <a href="contact/">Contact us</a>
  </div>
</div>
```